# Is there a way to make pdfpages adhere to the page offset set by geometry 

Tags: geometry, pdfpages

I'm trying to include some pdf documents at the end of my document using `pdfpages`. My document has a binding offset as defined using the `geometry` package but `pdfpages` doesn't recognise it. I've looked through the package options for `pdfpages` but can't see anything.

Comment: Did you know that [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) provides an offset in the form `\includepdf[offset=<offx> <offy>]{<filename>}` (see page 3 of the [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf)). Have you tried this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not only, as Werner suggests, there's the `offset=` option, but options to be used throughout can be specified *globally* via `\includepdfset`

```
\includepdfset{offset=0.7cm 0cm}
```

where instead of `0.7cm` there should be the amount of your binding correction. In twoside mode, this refers to a shift towards the outer margin, while in oneside mode it's always a shift to the right.

Insert that command just after loading **pdfpages**.

Comment: Thanks Werner and egreg, between the offset and realising you can use the graphicx scale option, I've managed to get it working nicely.